# Is server tag additive?

Tags: nginx

As this block would work perfectly for health check:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    location /health-check {
      access_log off;
      return 200;
      add_header Content-Type text/plain;
    }
  }
```

I am not sure if this would cause any issues on other server blocks that uses the same port, like for example:

```
server {
    listen 80 my-domain.com;
    ...
    ...
  }
```

would the above server block still working? or that server tag is not additive?

Answer (score 0):

```
**you not user duplicate server name or ip/
diffent serve block same port can not run
you give server name in config block
** 

server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/example.com/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name example.com www.example.com;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
```

you can genrate your nginx config using this tools https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tools/nginx